# Does the character 䐀 mean "put a pearl in the mouth of a deceased relative"?

Tags: meaning, character-identification

In a technology presentation, the presenter lists out several Chinese characters that gets printed out when there's an issue with how text is encoded: (Clicking the image below will lead to the YouTube video)

[image: Presentation of several Chinese characters]

The first character that he lists is [䐀](https://www.vazor.com/unicode/c4400.html), in which he says the following:

> I ran this through Google Translate ... The first one there is a character that means putting a pearl in the mouth of a deceased relative for burial

[image: Google Translate window listing that the translation for 䐀 is "Don't"]

[MDBG lists this as "to dismember body of a livestock".](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=chardict&cdcanoce=0&cdqchi=%E4%90%80%0D%0A)

**What does 䐀 mean?**

Answer (score 1):

The same video contains [this comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mZBa3sqTrI&lc=Ugyr2FHKrW-pKv4hkqN4AaABAg) that I should've read earlier:

> 䐀 (U+4400): to dismember body of the livestock
> 攀 (U+6500): to climb
> 氀 (U+6C00): a category of textile and fabrics
> 琀 (U+7400): gems/pearls/jade formerly put into the mouth of a corpse (note: this seems to be related to an ancient Chinese tradition/belief, that putting something, likely valuable, into the mouth of the corpse will lead the deceased to a better after life.)

The character that the presenter is probably referring to is 琀.